# Wordpress site not loading

Tags: wordpress

My wordpress site is not loading for some reason. It was working perfectly two days ago and now, whenever I try to access the home page, it stays loading. Same behaviour if I try to go to the admin page.

- I checked my server logs and nothing.
- Changed plugins forlder name and nothing
- enabled debug in wp-config and nothing

Any ideas?

Thanks

Console says that it fails to load css and javascript :S

Comment: I am in the development phase, so the site is on my laptop. I just changed the 'siteurl' and 'home' options in the wp_options table to 'localhost' and it started working again. I was using my IP address. So I am guessing it has to do with port forwarding?

Comment: Were you using dynamically assigned IP address or a fixed one? If you were using a dynamically assigned IP address then you're going to run into problems when it changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am in the development phase, so the site is on my laptop. I just changed the 'siteurl' and 'home' options in the wp_options table to 'localhost' and it started working again. I was using my IP address. So I am guessing it has to do with port forwarding?

After restarting the router, I was able to access the site again through my external IP address.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

My only suggestion would be to check and make sure that both your CSS and Javascript files are still in the same place as specified and to check the links to them.

Answer (score 0):

Use localhost in your site_url setting or be sure your IP doesn't change.